# Highlight all markers with the same feature value upon marker click in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, qgis2web

I have created a map with several points in qgis2web.
I was wondering if there is a way to edit the final leaflet JavaScript code or HMTL in order to, when clicking on one of the points in the map the points that are of the same feature are highlighted, base don the values on their attribute table.
For instance when a point is clicked and it has a location value in of the columns in its attribute table, all the points with the same location value are highlighted

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/L.Control.Locate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/qgis2web.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet-control-geocoder.Geocoder.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet-measure.css">
        <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map">
        </div>
        <script src="js/qgis2web_expressions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script><script src="js/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.pattern.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet-hash.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Autolinker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/rbush.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/labelgun.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/labels.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet-control-geocoder.Geocoder.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet-measure.js"></script>
        <script src="js/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
        <script src="data/SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7.js"></script>
        <script src="data/Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8.js"></script>
        <script src="data/Testemonials_9.js"></script>
        <script>
        var map = L.map('map', {
            zoomControl:true, maxZoom:28, minZoom:1
        }).fitBounds([[56.12758315677846,-5.851443281287844],[57.82274136452764,-1.688056020759287]]);
        var hash = new L.Hash(map);
        map.attributionControl.setPrefix('<a href="https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web" target="_blank">qgis2web</a> &middot; <a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> &middot; <a href="https://qgis.org">QGIS</a>');
        var autolinker = new Autolinker({truncate: {length: 30, location: 'smart'}});
        L.control.locate({locateOptions: {maxZoom: 19}}).addTo(map);
        var measureControl = new L.Control.Measure({
            position: 'topleft',
            primaryLengthUnit: 'feet',
            secondaryLengthUnit: 'miles',
            primaryAreaUnit: 'sqfeet',
            secondaryAreaUnit: 'sqmiles'
        });
        measureControl.addTo(map);
        document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-measure-toggle')[0]
        .innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-measure-toggle')[0]
        .className += ' fas fa-ruler';
        var bounds_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
        function setBounds() {
        }
        map.createPane('pane_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0');
        map.getPane('pane_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0').style.zIndex = 400;
        var layer_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0 = L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 0,
            maxNativeZoom: 18
        });
        layer_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0;
        map.addLayer(layer_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0);
        map.createPane('pane_RoyRoyHighlands17471752_1');
        map.getPane('pane_RoyRoyHighlands17471752_1').style.zIndex = 401;
        var layer_RoyRoyHighlands17471752_1 = L.tileLayer('https://mapseries-tilesets.s3.amazonaws.com/roy/highlands/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_RoyRoyHighlands17471752_1',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 5,
            maxNativeZoom: 15
        });
        layer_RoyRoyHighlands17471752_1;
        map.createPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotland19211930Regular19211930_2');
        map.getPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotland19211930Regular19211930_2').style.zIndex = 402;
        var layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotland19211930Regular19211930_2 = L.tileLayer('https://mapseries-tilesets.s3.amazonaws.com/popular/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotland19211930Regular19211930_2',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 1,
            maxNativeZoom: 15
        });
        layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotland19211930Regular19211930_2;
        map.createPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotlandCol18571891_3');
        map.getPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotlandCol18571891_3').style.zIndex = 403;
        var layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotlandCol18571891_3 = L.tileLayer('https://mapseries-tilesets.s3.amazonaws.com/os/one-inch-first-bart38/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotlandCol18571891_3',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 1,
            maxNativeZoom: 15
        });
        layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotlandCol18571891_3;
        map.createPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInch19451948Regular18451948_4');
        map.getPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInch19451948Regular18451948_4').style.zIndex = 404;
        var layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInch19451948Regular18451948_4 = L.tileLayer('https://mapseries-tilesets.s3.amazonaws.com/os/1inch_pop_nat_grid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_OrdnanceSurveyOneInch19451948Regular18451948_4',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 1,
            maxNativeZoom: 15
        });
        layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInch19451948Regular18451948_4;
        map.createPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyHalfInchHills19081918_5');
        map.getPane('pane_OrdnanceSurveyHalfInchHills19081918_5').style.zIndex = 405;
        var layer_OrdnanceSurveyHalfInchHills19081918_5 = L.tileLayer('https://mapseries-tilesets.s3.amazonaws.com/half-inch-hills/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_OrdnanceSurveyHalfInchHills19081918_5',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 1,
            maxNativeZoom: 13
        });
        layer_OrdnanceSurveyHalfInchHills19081918_5;
        map.createPane('pane_BartholomewBartholomewHalfInch18971907_6');
        map.getPane('pane_BartholomewBartholomewHalfInch18971907_6').style.zIndex = 406;
        var layer_BartholomewBartholomewHalfInch18971907_6 = L.tileLayer('https://mapseries-tilesets.s3.amazonaws.com/bartholomew_great_britain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            pane: 'pane_BartholomewBartholomewHalfInch18971907_6',
            opacity: 1.0,
            attribution: '',
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 28,
            minNativeZoom: 1,
            maxNativeZoom: 15
        });
        layer_BartholomewBartholomewHalfInch18971907_6;
        function pop_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7(feature, layer) {
        }

        function style_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7',
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'rgba(255,0,0,1.0)',
                dashArray: '',
                lineCap: 'butt',
                lineJoin: 'miter',
                weight: 2.0, 
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(164,113,88,0.0)',
                interactive: false,
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7');
        map.getPane('pane_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7').style.zIndex = 407;
        map.getPane('pane_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7 = new L.geoJson(json_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7, {
            attribution: '',
            interactive: false,
            dataVar: 'json_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7',
            layerName: 'layer_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7',
            pane: 'pane_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7',
            onEachFeature: pop_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7,
            style: style_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7_0,
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7);
        map.addLayer(layer_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7);
        function pop_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['CATEGORY'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['CATEGORY'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['COUNTRY'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['COUNTRY'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['Area_ha'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['Area_ha'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        }

        function style_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8',
                stroke: false, 
                fill: true,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                fillColor: 'rgba(69,97,59,1.0)',
                interactive: true,
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8');
        map.getPane('pane_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8').style.zIndex = 408;
        map.getPane('pane_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8 = new L.geoJson(json_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8, {
            attribution: '',
            interactive: true,
            dataVar: 'json_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8',
            layerName: 'layer_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8',
            pane: 'pane_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8',
            onEachFeature: pop_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8,
            style: style_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8_0,
        });
        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8);
        map.addLayer(layer_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8);
        function pop_Testemonials_9(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = '<table>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Example th</strong><br />' + (feature.properties['Example th'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['Example th'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2">' + (feature.properties['LOCATION'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['LOCATION'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                    <tr>\
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>LINK</strong><br />' + (feature.properties['LINK'] !== null ? autolinker.link(feature.properties['LINK'].toLocaleString()) : '') + '</td>\
                    </tr>\
                </table>';
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent, {maxHeight: 400});
        }

        function style_Testemonials_9_0() {
            return {
                pane: 'pane_Testemonials_9',
        rotationAngle: 0.0,
        rotationOrigin: 'center center',
        icon: L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'markers/tree-svgrepo-com.svg',
            iconSize: [57.0, 57.0]
        }),
                interactive: true,
            }
        }
        map.createPane('pane_Testemonials_9');
        map.getPane('pane_Testemonials_9').style.zIndex = 409;
        map.getPane('pane_Testemonials_9').style['mix-blend-mode'] = 'normal';
        var layer_Testemonials_9 = new L.geoJson(json_Testemonials_9, {
            attribution: '',
            interactive: true,
            dataVar: 'json_Testemonials_9',
            layerName: 'layer_Testemonials_9',
            pane: 'pane_Testemonials_9',
            onEachFeature: pop_Testemonials_9,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                var context = {
                    feature: feature,
                    variables: {}
                };
                return L.marker(latlng, style_Testemonials_9_0(feature));
            },
        });
        var cluster_Testemonials_9 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover: false,
            spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 2});
        cluster_Testemonials_9.addLayer(layer_Testemonials_9);

        bounds_group.addLayer(layer_Testemonials_9);
        cluster_Testemonials_9.addTo(map);
        var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder({
            collapsed: true,
            position: 'topleft',
            text: 'Search',
            title: 'Testing'
        }).addTo(map);
        document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-geocoder-icon')[0]
        .className += ' fa fa-search';
        document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-geocoder-icon')[0]
        .title += 'Search for a place';
        var baseMaps = {};
        L.control.layers(baseMaps,{'<img src="legend/Testemonials_9.png" /> Testemonials': cluster_Testemonials_9,'<img src="legend/Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8.png" /> Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms': layer_Forest_Inventory_Cairngorms_8,'<img src="legend/SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7.png" /> SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010': layer_SG_CairngormsNationalPark_2010_7,"Bartholomew - Bartholomew Half Inch, 1897-1907": layer_BartholomewBartholomewHalfInch18971907_6,"Ordnance Survey - Half-Inch (Hills), 1908-1918": layer_OrdnanceSurveyHalfInchHills19081918_5,"Ordnance Survey - One Inch, 1945-1948 (Regular), 1845-1948": layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInch19451948Regular18451948_4,"Ordnance Survey - One Inch Scotland (Col), 1857-1891": layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotlandCol18571891_3,"Ordnance Survey - One Inch Scotland, 1921-1930 (Regular), 1921-1930 ": layer_OrdnanceSurveyOneInchScotland19211930Regular19211930_2,"Roy - Roy Highlands, 1747-1752": layer_RoyRoyHighlands17471752_1,"OSM Humanitarian Data Model": layer_OSMHumanitarianDataModel_0,}).addTo(map);
        setBounds();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have added code

Comment: Nowhere in your code you are processing point click and then point selection. Now on point click popup opens. What do you want to happen on point click? Popup or point selection? How would point selection look like? I also don't see any `location` attribute for your points. Please edit your question and add more info.

Comment: sorry of the poor quality. I have added code that is more close to what I asked. I would want after the click on the point and the pop-up happens to have all the points with the same attribute to be highlighted

Comment: Which attribute, there are many? And what exactly do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: There is an attribute that describes the location of each point. And by highlight, I mean to either mark the points with a halo or change their symbology temporarily

Comment: Do you have any understanding of the Leaflet code in your question?

Comment: Some of it. I have made some modifications for pop up size and market style

Comment: Which is the point layer you are interested in? Is it `layer_Testemonials_9`? If it is, there will be problems highlighting all the affected points, since it is source for `cluster_Testemonials_9` ckuster layer, which means some points might be clustered.

Comment: That's the layer I need to make the highlight but i believe it might be ok if theu are clustered. In the end i can remove clustering

Comment: Can you share you data `data/Testemonials_9.js`, so I can do some real life tests?

Comment: The data is available here. https://easyupload.io/lpbxmj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be to define `popupopen` and `popupclose` event processing functions for `layer_Testemonials_9` marker layer and there do all the necessary processing.

Function for `popupopen` event would do the following:

- Clear any previously highlighted markers. This means setting their icon to normal marker icon.
- Check contents of marker feature `LOCATION` property.
- If `LOCATION` property is empty, setting marker icon to selected marker icon.
- If `LOCATION` property is not empty, iterate through all the layer markers and set their icon to selected icon if `LOCATION` property matched clicked marker `LOCATION` property.

Function for `popupclose` event would just clear any previously highlighted markers.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this (names do not match names from question):

```
var treeIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'img/tree.svg',
    iconSize: [32, 32],
    iconAnchor: [16, 32],
    shadowUrl: null
});
var treeIcon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'img/tree2.svg',
    iconSize: [32, 32],
    iconAnchor: [16, 32],
    shadowUrl: null
});

var clusteredMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  maxClusterRadius: 25,
  spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true
});

var markers = L.geoJSON(json_Joinedlayer_5, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.marker(latlng,{icon: treeIcon});
    var popupTxt = feature.properties.code;
    if (feature.properties.LOCATION) {
      popupTxt += ', ' + feature.properties.LOCATION;
    }
    marker.bindPopup(popupTxt, {offset: [0, -24], closeOnClick: true});
    clusteredMarkers.addLayer(marker);
    return(marker);
  }
});
map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

var selectedMarkers = [];

function clearSelection() {
  selectedMarkers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setIcon(treeIcon);
  });
  selectedMarkers = [];
}

markers.on('popupopen', function(evt) {
  clearSelection();
  var marker = evt.layer;
  var location = marker.feature.properties.LOCATION;
  if (!location) {
    marker.setIcon(treeIcon2);
    selectedMarkers.push(marker);
    }  
  else {
    markers.eachLayer(function(marker) {
      if (marker.feature.properties.LOCATION == location) {
        marker.setIcon(treeIcon2);
        selectedMarkers.push(marker);
      }
    });
  }
});
markers.on('popupclose', function(evt) {
  if (selectedMarkers.length > 0) clearSelection();
});
```

Here is how such a selection would then look like for marker with the same value for the `LOCATION` property:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!!! I came up with something too, your solution uses costum svg, whihc better.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution too, but [TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm) is way better as it uses custom svgs.

Mine was highlighting only simple circle markers.

'''

```
        <script> 
        var selectedAttributeValue = null;
    
        // Define a function to highlight features with the same attribute value
        function highlightFeaturesWithSameAttribute(attributeValue) {
            map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                if (layer.feature && layer.feature.properties.NAME_0 === attributeValue) {
                    layer.setStyle({
                        weight: 3,  // Adjust the highlight style as needed
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    
        // Reset the style for all features
        function resetFeatureStyles() {
            map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                if (layer.feature) {
                    layer.setStyle({
                        color : 'red',
                        weight: 1,  // Reset the style as needed
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    
        // Attach a click event listener to each feature
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer.feature) {
                layer.on('click', function (e) {
                    // Get the clicked feature's attribute value
                    var attributeValue = e.target.feature.properties.NAME_0;
    
                    if (selectedAttributeValue === attributeValue) {
                        // If the same point is clicked again, reset styles
                        resetFeatureStyles();
                        selectedAttributeValue = null;
                    } else {
                        // Reset the style for all features
                        resetFeatureStyles();
    
                        // Highlight features with the same attribute value
                        highlightFeaturesWithSameAttribute(attributeValue);
    
                        selectedAttributeValue = attributeValue;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>'''
```